# How to automatically deploy and update software to domain users

Tags: windows-server-2008, deployment, update

We have a set of software programs every employee uses. How is it possible to automatically install that software as soon as an employee is logging in to our domain and does not have it installed currently? Also that software should be kept up to date automatically for everyone. Does Windows Server 2008 have that functionality or is that only possible using third party programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Group Policy's Software Distribution ability:
Details here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102/en

This does not automatically update your software, you have to do this yourself (but you can do it through GPO as well)

Other than this, you can do homegrown scripts to Install/Update software, or you need to use third party software. (e.g. Microsoft's SCCM), but product recommendations are off-topic at serverfault anyways.